# Having Trouble With a Recursion Problem that Converts a String to an Int

Tags: java, string, recursion, methods, integer

So the problem is as follows. You are to create a method that takes a string as a parameter that consists of all numbers and you need to take that string and convert it to an Integer. You have to use a recursive solution to solve the problem.

I have written the following code and it works just fine when I enter "1234" or "138775" but as soon as I enter a number that contains 0 it returns a weird result.

100, 1001, 101, and 12045 return 10, 11, 110, and 1245 respectively. As mentioned above The code works just fine when I send it things like "1234" or "14384" but as soon as there is a zero it has a tendency to remove that zero.

I have tried different int to string conversions from the Integer class such as parse(int) but that had the same result.

```
/**
 * converts a string of numbers to an int
 * 
 * @param String str: original string of numbers
 * @return int recursiveStringInt: returns the int value of the string
 */
public static int recursiveStringInt(String str)
{
    if(str.length() == 1)
        return Integer.valueOf(str);
    else
    {
        return Integer.valueOf(str.substring(0,1) + recursiveStringInt(str.substring(1)));
    }
}
```

Thanks for your guys help!

Please let me know if there is any clarification needed.

Comment: Consider `System.out.println(Integer.valueOf("0123"));`

Comment: I think that your code is supposed to be dividing and using powers of 10 of something

Comment: You should be asking these kind of questions on Code Review and not Stackoverflow. T

Comment: What is the "weird result"? Knowing that can help us to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your parentheses are a bit off for what you're trying to do, and the logic needs some work..  what you want is to take the *last* character of the current string, convert it to an integer, and add it to the conversion of the front of the string times 10.

```
int recursiveStringInt(String str) {
    int length = str.length()
    if(length == 1)
        return Integer.valueOf(str);
    else
    {
        int temp = Integer.valueOf(str.substring(length-1)) + ( 10 * recursiveStringInt(str.substring(0,length-1)));
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Trivial case of "8" results in just the first block being executed.

Next case of "83" results in temp = 3 + (10 * 8) = 83

Next case of "103" results in temp = 3 + (10 * (0 + (10 * 1))) = 103

Answer (score 0):

Try using a divide and power solution

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(recursiveStringInt("12034", 0));

}

public static int recursiveStringInt(String str, int pow)
{
    if(str.length() < 1)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        int temp = Integer.valueOf(str.substring(str.length() -1)) 
                                                       * (int) Math.pow(10.0, 1.0 * pow);
        temp += recursiveStringInt(str.substring(0, str.length() -1), pow + 1);
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to split it out to make it easier for the OP to understand, although yours is better.

Comment: no problem what-so-ever - need more coffee though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you parse a substring like `054` to int, it becomes `54`.

Try this code:-

```
public static int recursiveStringInt(String str) {
    return str.length() == 1
            ? Integer.valueOf(str)
            : (int) (Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0, 1)) * Math.pow(10, str.length() - 1)) + recursiveStringInt(str.substring(1));
}
```

I have used this logic:-

`105 = 1*100 + 0*10 + 5*1`

Edit: If you don't understand the ternary operator, here is the if-else version:-

```
public static int recursiveStringInt(String str) {
    if (str.length() == 1) {
        return Integer.valueOf(str);
    } else {
        return (int) (Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0, 1)) * Math.pow(10, str.length() - 1)) + recursiveStringInt(str.substring(1));
    }
}
```